# How to integrate ready servlets in gwt or jsf?

Tags: jsf, gwt, jakarta-ee, servlets

I already made my servlets in Java. But now, I want to make some fancy web pages. I thought of using GWT or JSF. But it looks like I will have to repeat all the job that I made in my Servlets. Can I use my ready servlets in GWT or JSF without having to change a lot in my servlets

Comment: Why do you think you have to remake them? A Servlet is a very abstract thing - if it is sending an html page back, then you might not need GWT or JSF, if it is sending JSON or some other data then either a GWT or JSF page can make use of that data just as easily. More detail is required.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do so then your servlets are poorly designed in first place. It sounds like that the model is tight coupled into the servlet instead of being standalone in flavor of for example EJBs/Entities. There's nothing to do against this other than rewriting the code so that your model is reusable in both the "plain" servlet/JSP webapp and the JSF webapp (and any other MVC framework). Ask if necessary help to a more experienced Java EE developer/architect in your team.